# A remote service with cross-platform, cross-language interface

Tags: web-services, wcf

I am sorry for an abstract newbie question, because I am looking something like cross-language WCF.

Let's say I have an abstract service running on a server. The service implements some logic, accesses a database and exposes some interface to the client application for sending and receiving data (more a simple request-response, than a bidirectional real time, not message-based).

What are the modern and the most convenient approaches for implementing the service interface assuming the clients can be written in C++, C#, Java on Windows, Android, iOS and WEB, in other words everywhere. The service should have object-oriented interfaces in the client native languages (like WCF does in C#, for example). The network protocols can be HTTP or TCP.

As far as I see the service can be implemented on Java (with Tomcat, for example), or with Mono (using WCF, for example), but it is not clear for me, how the heterogeneous clients in different languages will consume it.

Another option is Protobuf or JSON, but as far as I see they are only a mechanism of data serialization, but not the communication with the server. So I interested in a list of the modern and widely used approaches. The key point also is the client authentication, supporting user sessions, session status, etc...

Comment: Well, the basic core architecture of **interoperable web services** is very much at odds with the principles of object-oriented programming. Interoperable web services (e.g. WCF) are based on **serialized XML messages** which can handle anything that can be expressed in **XML schema** - but that does **not support** interfaces, it does not support abstract classes and many more things. If you use a SOA approach - it will *not* be fully object-oriented - not at its core

Comment: what should I install on the server and what libraries to use on clients in C++/C#/Java/JavaScript?

Comment: You can basically install whatever technology you like on the server side - as long as it plays nicely and fully supports interoperable web services, then it really doesn't matter which technology stack you're using. Use the one you're most familiar with and that fits the best for your development. As for the clients - that depends on each client, but most of these languages / systems will fully support interoperable SOAP services. If you have clients with only an HTTP stack, you might want to use REST/JSON based services

Comment: Is it a good idea to use Mono with WCF at the server side, or probably Java would be better, probably because Java has some kind of application templates that can be used as starting point for building the app (but I am not sure about this)?